# Android : cannot input text from keyboard

Tags: keyboard, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

When my android sdk update to newest version, i met the issue is : I cannot type text into Android Emulator by using computer keyboard, and I cannot use Android Emulator keyboard (the keyboard that next to the screen).

If I want to input some text, I must use this : click to textfield where I want to type. It will go to screen with virtual keyboard (as a real mobile phone), and click the character I want.

This annoy me because make me slower when debug an app. Please help me, how to type directly using keyboard.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add "Keyboard support" to your emulator hardware:

- On Eclipse, go to Window > AVD Manager
- Choose your emulator > Edit
- Click "New" button in "Hardware" section
- Select "Keyboard support" and change value to "Yes"
- Finally, click on "Edit AVD" button.

Then you could input text to your emulator from your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - since I upgraded to sdk v14, I've had settings issues on the emulators.  Leap's solution does work, but you might have to start and stop the emulator *several* times before these settings stick. No idea why that is ...